# Trapezoidal integration rule error analysis.

Tags: numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation, quadrature

Let $f(x)\in C^2[a,b]$ and $p\in P_1$ its Lagrange interpolation polynom for nodes $a,b$:
$$p(a) = f(a), ~p(b) = f(b).$$
Then the interpolation error is
$$f(x) - p(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-a)(x-b)f''(\xi(x)), ~\xi(x)\in[a,b]$$
It follows from calculation of $p(x)$ that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \frac{b-a}{2}(f(a)+f(b)) + \int_a^b\frac{1}{2}(x-a)(x-b)f''(\xi(x))dx$$
Now, in my homework I am to prove that
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = \frac{b-a}{2}(f(a)+f(b)) + \int_a^b\frac{1}{2}(x-a)(x-b)f''(x)dx$$
Is this a misprint? And if not, how can one possible derive that representation? I also tried the divided difference error representation with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate backwards, with partial integration:
\begin{align}
\int_a^b(x-a)(x-b)f''(x)dx
&=[(x-a)(x-b)f'(x)]_a^b-\int_a^b(2x-a-b)f'(x)dx\\
&=0-0-[(2x-a-b)f(x)]_a^b+\int_a^b2f(x)dx\\
&=-(b-a)(f(b)+f(a))+2\int_a^bf(x)dx
\end{align}
so that indeed the claimed identity holds.